# why does getelementbyid not work with dynamically added html in javascript without libraries

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, native

for my school project I have to make a website that is singlepage but I cannot use libraries.

I found this javascript code to achieve this main.js:

```
// Encapsulates an HTTP GET request using XMLHttpRequest.
// Fetches the file at the given path, then
// calls the callback with the text content of the file.
function fetchFile(path, callback){

    // Create a new AJAX request for fetching the partial HTML file.
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Call the callback with the content loaded from the file.
    request.onload = function () {
        callback(request.responseText);
    };

    // Fetch the partial HTML file for the given fragment id.
    request.open("GET", path);
    request.send(null);
}

// Gets the appropriate content for the given fragment identifier.
function getContent(fragmentId, callback){
    fetchFile( fragmentId + ".html", callback );
}

// Sets the "active" class on the active navigation link.
function setActiveLink(fragmentId) {
    if (fragmentId != "login") {

    var navbarDiv = document.getElementById("navbar"),
        links = navbarDiv.children,
        i, link, pageName;
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        link = links[i];
        pageName = link.getAttribute("href").substr(1);
        if (pageName === fragmentId) {
            link.setAttribute("class", "active");
        } else {
            link.removeAttribute("class");
        }
    }
}
}

// Updates dynamic content based on the fragment identifier.
function navigate(){

    // Get a reference to the "content" div.
    var contentDiv = document.getElementById("content"),

        // Isolate the fragment identifier using substr.
        // This gets rid of the "#" character.
        fragmentId = location.hash.substr(1);

    // Set the "content" div innerHTML based on the fragment identifier.
    getContent(fragmentId, function (content) {
        contentDiv.innerHTML = content;
    });

    // Toggle the "active" class on the link currently navigated to.
    setActiveLink(fragmentId);
}

// If no fragment identifier is provided,
if(!location.hash) {

    // default to #home.
    location.hash = "#login";
}

// Navigate once to the initial fragment identifier.
navigate();

// Navigate whenever the fragment identifier value changes.
window.addEventListener("hashchange", navigate);
```

My index html where I load in the dynamic html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Navigation Example</title>

</head>
<body>

<!-- Dynamic content will be placed here by JavaScript. -->
<div id="content"></div>

<!-- The JavaScript code for dynamic behavior. -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/login.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

this is the dynamically added html file with main.js:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="signin">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
            </div>
            <form>
                <div>
                    <label>Gebruikersnaam</label>
                    <input type="text" class="text-input" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Wachtwoord</label>
                    <input type="password" class="text-input" />
                </div>
                <button id="button-login" type="button" class="primary-btn">Inloggen</button>
            </form>
            <div class="links">
                <a href="#">Wachtwoord vergeten</a>
                <a href="#">Login als quiz beheerder</a>
            </div>
            <div class="or">
                <hr class="bar" />
                <span>OF</span>
                <hr class="bar" />
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="secondary-btn">Maak een nieuw account aan</a>
        </div>
        <footer id="main-footer">
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2019, Thomas Ponzo Alle rechten voorbehouden</p>
            <div>
                <a href="#">Gebruiksvoorwaarden</a> | <a href="#">Privacybeleid</a>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="showcase">
            <div class="showcase-content">
                <h1 class="showcase-text">
                    Beoordeel de  <strong>Website!</strong>
                </h1>
                <a id="button-document" class="secondary-btn">Start het beoordelingsproces</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

login.js :

```
/**
 * Add actions to page buttons 
 */
function addButtonActions() {
    var loginButton = document.getElementById('button-login');
    var documentButton = document.getElementById('button-document');

    loginButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        showStartPage();
    });
    documentButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        showDocumentPage();
    });
}

/**
 * Show start page
 */
function showStartPage() {
    window.open("quizhome.html", "_self");
    console.log("test")
}

/**
 * Show questions page
 */
function showDocumentPage() {
window.open("documentation/index.html", '_blank');
}

// Updates dynamic content based on the fragment identifier.
function navigate(){

    // Get a reference to the "content" div.
    var contentDiv = document.getElementById("content"),

        // Isolate the fragment identifier using substr.
        // This gets rid of the "#" character.
        fragmentId = location.hash.substr(1);

    // Set the "content" div innerHTML based on the fragment identifier.
    getContent(fragmentId, function (content) {
        contentDiv.innerHTML = content;
    });

    // Toggle the "active" class on the link currently navigated to.
    setActiveLink(fragmentId);
};

// Sets the "active" class on the active navigation link.
function setActiveLink(fragmentId) {
    if (fragmentId == "login") {
        addButtonActions();
    }
};

// Navigate once to the initial fragment identifier.
navigate();
```

my problem is that I cant get a reference for my buttons in login.js my question is how can I archieve this in javascript without using libraries?

Comment: What is index.js and what is login.js ? You only posted 1 js-snippet.

Comment: Not allowed to use any libraries and then copying some code found on the web... Did you consider that maybe the idea behind this assignment is for you to work out your own logic and come up with something yourself to demonstrate your understanding of JavaScript and web development techniques?

Comment: I don't see the `login.js` you've mentioned, but the asynchronous nature of what you're doing is probably the issue. You should only look for the dynamic elements (and attach event listeners) **after** the content has been loaded and injected into the DOM.

Comment: in the html, you reference `index.js` but not `login.js`

Comment: @Thomas Ponzo Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: yes I added a small delay before setting the variables